# unable to use c++amp in vs 2017

Tags: visual-c++, c++-amp

I tried to use C++ amp in Visual Studio 2017, but compiler said, "error C3564" and I tried the old code(which worked in Visual Studio 2015), and it said same thing.
Does Visual Studio 2017 support C++ amp?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace concurrency;
int main(void){
    int size;
    scanf_s("%d", &size);
    array_view<int, 1> a(1);
    parallel_for_each(extent<1>(1),
    [=](index<1> &idx) restrict(amp)
    {
        a(idx) = size;
    });
}
```

the code above will generate problem.

Comment: Show your code please..

Comment: @AshwinGolani I found the part where error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

just added the amp.h file and the code above compiles.

i am also working on other project with C++AMP in vs 2017 and it working fine.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <amp.h>

using namespace concurrency;

int main(void) {
    int size;
    scanf_s("%d", &size);
    array_view<int, 1> a(1);
    parallel_for_each(extent<1>(1),
        [=](index<1> &idx) restrict(amp)
    {
        a(idx) = size;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was a bug on VS, and they fixed it on later release. [Link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/33349/c-amp-bug.html)